# Eclipse - Git Push HEAD when no changes

Tags: git, eclipse, push, egit

On Eclipse when checking Git Staging view with no changes

There's an option/button to **Push HEAD** and I can click and after preview I can Push

What will happen when pushing HEAD with no changes?

Is there any affect/use case of doing push with no changes?

If not why eclipse suggest/allow it?

[image]

Comment: In the dialog there is a checkbox at the bottom, which is cut off in your screenshot: _Cancel push if result would be different than above because of changes on remote_.

Comment: @howlger it's irrelevant to my question, why would I push if no changes

Comment: The preview differs when changes have been made in the meantime on remote. That also answers your question, doesn't it?

Comment: The push HEAD button had been explicitly asked for on Eclipse bugzilla. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512457 Would this answer your question?

Comment: @Snoeren01 not exactly, can you answer a detailed answer why we need it?

Comment: @user7294900 I am still struggling to understand the intricacies of Git so I am afraid that I might end up writing a wrong answer. If I understood the initial comment on Eclipse Bugzilla correctly, 'git rebase' leads to a situation where there are no changes to be committed but you still might want to push the result of this operation to the online repository. Previously you needed to change something in a file so that the 'Push and Commit' button becomes active again. The 'push HEAD' button solves this more elegantly.